# Break a HTML Table to two tables dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I am using an user control in asp.net in which I am creating a html table from code behind. Initial structure is given below.

```
 <table>
  <tr>
        <td>Property1</td>
        <td>Property2</td>
        <td>Property3</td>
        <td>Property4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value3</td>
        <td>Value4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is I want to restructure it according to the size of container it is going to be placed [as it is a user control]. For Ex If width of each cell is 20px and container width is 40px then structure will be as given below;

```
    <table>
  <tr>
        <td>Property1</td>
        <td>Property2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
  </tr>
   </table>



<table>
   <tr>
        <td>Property3</td>
        <td>Property4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
        <td>Value3</td>
        <td>Value4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And where are the two tables mention in your title?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259675/split-a-table-in-half there is similar question

Comment: I have to implement in IE. and the solution given in above post is not working in ie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @user2167382.
Finally I have solved it though I had to use jquery.
Below is my html.

```
    <table id="sourceT">
<tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Col 1 - value</td>
    <td>Col 2 - value</td>
    <td>Col 3 - value</td>
</tr>
 </table>



 <table id="targetT">
 </table>
```

Here is the jquery logic.

```
var $target = $("#targetT");

$("#sourceT tr").each(function() {
var $tds = $(this).children(),
    $row = $("<tr></tr>");
    var i=1;
 while(i<3)
 {
  alert(i)  ;  $row.append($tds.eq(i).clone()).appendTo($target);
    i++;

 }
});
```

Hope it will help somebody else.